# Emoji inserts Play Framework

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, emoji

I am using play framework 2.0.x, I am having an issue with Emoji inserts, it seems the SQL class is converting these into the mapped string values instead of the correct character I'm trying to insert. I'v already tested things on MySQL and works flawlessly with utf8mb4 settings, this only happens when doing the insert with play and I narrowed it down to whatever is building the query doing the conversion before insert.

Can clearly see the conversion is happening in this query within the SQL object

```
SQL(
                  """
                      UPDATE users SET 
                      first_name={fname}
                      , last_name={lname}
                      , email={email}
                      , birthdate={bday}
                      , gender={sex}
                      WHERE user_id={userId} 
                  """
                  ).on(
                      'userId -> userId,
                      'fname -> fname,
                      'lname -> lname,
                      'email -> email.trim,
                      'bday ->bday,
                      'sex -> gender
                  ).executeUpdate()

Execution exception [[SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x9A' for column 'first_name' at row 1]]
```

Of course I am expecting to see an Emoji icon at this point, which is .

Is there a character encoding I need to change for play? Any ideas are appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding 'SET NAMES utf8mb4' before the query solved this issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8

Comment: This does not work as the encoding is utf8mb4 on the server side. I tried this with no luck.